# Feeding text file as standart input

Tags: java, linux, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write program to called `Triangle.java`. The program should read  3 Integers from file as standard input and use them as parameters.

I did something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
  String TestName = input.nextLine();
  int x = input.nextInt();
  int y = input.nextInt();
  int z = input.nextInt();
  .......
}
```

and then I wanted to use `x`,`y` and `z` as parameters. I tried to compile the program on my ubuntu machine using command line  javac `Triangle.java<test.txt` then run program using java `Triangle.class`.

Things do not seem to be working. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I do not see any question or problem statement in your question?

Comment: Just a little advice/guideline: variable name begin with lowercase: TestName -> testName. This may also resolve some issues

Comment: In addiction "Things do not seem to be working" is not enough to understand what kind of problem you've had. Please post your expected result vs your actual and in case your error

Comment: Please, describe what seems to be the problem. It sounds like it doesn't compile, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, a couple of problems with that code, but here's your main problem: You read more than you have

```
String TestName=input.nextLine();
int x =input.nextInt();
int y =input.nextInt();
int z =input.nextInt();
```

`input.nextLine()` will already read the ENTIRE line. So `input.nextInt()` will try to read ints from the next line yet again of which you don't even know if it exists.

That's not so much a problem with `System.in` because it will just prompt the user to enter some more ints (though I don't see how the `TestName` variable will be of any use anyway). But if you're using a file, this will become a problem.

Also, as a side note:

You can't really call `input.hasNextLine()` on a `Scanner` using `System.in`, because at that point in time, there will be no next line in the input stream. You first have to prompt the user to input some more before there will be a line, which means your `while` will never be executed.

However when you're using a file, obviously the check will work, so you should keep it around anyway.

Comment: Thanks. it helped a lot. I just got rid of input.nextline() and TestName. It is working